# Does ReflectionOnlyLoad initialize or otherwise run any code?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

For a project I'm working on I have to analyze several dozen assemblies.

It is very important that none of the code contained within these assemblies is actually being run, therefore I looked at `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`, as [the documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload.aspx) mentions:

> Loads an assembly into the reflection-only context, where it can be
>   examined but not executed. This member is overloaded. For complete
>   information about this member, including syntax, usage, and examples,
>   click a name in the overload list.

Now I know regular `Assembly.Load` runs either the initializers or the constructors of the objects it loads, but am I right in the assumption that this is not the case for `ReflectionOnlyLoad`, or should I be looking into other ways of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReflectionOnlyLoad` will indeed forbid any code from the assembly from executing. It also has its own issues - notably, it's not cabaple of loading any dependencies. This can be tricky, since reflecting on a class deriving from a type defined in a different assembly will fail.

As far as I'm aware, `Assembly.Load` <s>will not run anything in the assembly by default</s> (**EDIT**: except for the module initializers, which could be abused; if you're not concerned with "hackers", this is not a problem, since normal C# code can't write module initializers, but it can be added in IL, and it might be present in C++/CLI assemblies), until you actually make it do so - for example, trying to get a value of a static field somewhere - but then again, doing that in a reflection only context will cause an exception.

In any case, whether you use `ReflectionOnlyLoad` or just plain old `Load`, make sure you're loading the assembly into a separate application domain. This lets you define different security contexts (no full trust for untrusted assemblies) and just as importantly, unload the assembly when you're done with it. If you don't load it in a separate application domain, you're not getting rid of the assembly until you restart your whole application.

Comment: For Assembly.Load, also take a look at this: http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oops. That's quite useful, and quite unsafe. Of course, you can still sandbox it in its own AppDomain, and make sure it has as little permissions as possible, but it still means there's ways to make the assembly dangerous (e.g. a simple never-ending loop). The damage is still limited if you only let the assembly load in an untrusted context, but it could be trouble.